# Why is cin.ignore() ignoring the first character of my getline input?

Tags: c++, cin, getline

So according to Eclipse, the getline function stores the entire text line from stream along with the newline and "terminating null character." I don't entirely know what that means.

The output I'm trying to get is printing two parallel arrays using a function. This function is a void function holding 3 parameters, the first array, the second array, and the constant integer array size value.

I'm able to store input into the first array with no problem.

```
    const int SIZE = 5;
    double firstArray[SIZE];

    // range-based `for` loop to get user input
    for (double& floatNum : firstArray)
    {
        cout << "Enter a floating point number: ";
        cin >> floatNum;
    }
```

However, things get weird with the second array, which is a string type.

```
    string secondArray[SIZE];

    // `for` loop to get user input
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter a name: ";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, secondArray[i]);
    }
```

My desired output is to print out both arrays using a function call in `main()`, `printParallel(array1, array2, sizeofarray)`, simultaneously using a `while` loop inside a function, which I've attempted here:

```
void printParallel(double arrayOne[], string arrayTwo[], const int NUM)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < NUM)
    {
        cout << arrayOne[i] << " " << arrayTwo[i] << endl;
        i++;
    }

}
```

But the output is slightly off:

```
Enter a floating point number: 1.23
Enter a floating point number: 1.23
Enter a floating point number: 1.23
Enter a floating point number: 1.23
Enter a floating point number: 1.23
Enter a name: AA AA
Enter a name: AA AA
Enter a name: AA AA
Enter a name: AA AA
Enter a name: AA AA
1.23 AA AA
1.23 A AA
1.23 A AA
1.23 A AA
1.23 A AA
```

Can someone explain what's going on here? The first "A" seems to be overwritten by a null character. Also, is there a better way I should be asking questions in order to solve problems better in the future?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

`cin.ignore();` *inside the loop*

This is equivalent to `cin.ignore(1);`

It is ignoring every first character of your string inputs. That is why, all those *"AA AA"* become *"A AA"* (the first 'A' is ignored by `cin.ignore()`).

Except the first *"AA AA"*. In this case, `cin.ignore()` actually ignores the `\n` after entering the last floating point number from the previous loop. So, the first string output is luckily correct.

**Solution:**

Call `cin.ignore()` just once before entering that loop instead of calling it for every single string input.

`getline(cin, secondArray[i]);` eats the `\n` at the end of those inputs and you need not `cin.ignore()` them.

```
// `for` loop to get user input
cin.ignore(); // solution
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter a name: ";
    // cin.ignore(); <-- Mistake
    getline(cin, secondArray[i]);
}
```